# How to use mysql2/promise in express route?

Tags: node.js

the error said connection async function is not function. but definetly is a function. what the error is exatcly?

> connection(...).execute is not a function

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const options =
{
    'host'              : '127.0.0.1',
    'port'              : 3306,
    'user'              : 'pandora',
    'password'          : 'pandora',
    'database'          : 'pandora',
    'supportBigNumbers' : true
};

async function connection(){
    return await mysql.createConnection(options);
}
```

route

```
app.get('/', async () => {
  const [rows] = await connection().execute('SELECT * FROM media');

  res.send(rows.length);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await connection first inorder to use execute function:

```
const [rows] = await (await connection()).execute('SELECT * FROM media');
```

OR

```
const conn = await connection();
const [rows] = await conn.execute('SELECT * FROM media');
```

Comment: But still it my endpoint keep refresh. dont return the row. and give unhandled ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE

Comment: That seems like different issue. try to debug `console.log(rows)` and check value of rows before returning. or better to wrap in try catch and console/throw error in catch to check issue.

Comment: Or i think you forgot to pass `req,res` params in app.get callback

Comment: if i just use pass rows. it output the data. but with attribute length. `rows.length`. it return error send function is deprecated. instead use sendStatus. so i use sendStatus. then, it return `[ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE] `. what the problem here? length attribute return integer. what that it error? should i cast it to string first?

Comment: Okay, send function accept string only. I cast it into string. it now return the length

Answer (score 1):

You need to await the `connection()` itself, then execute:

```js
app.get('/', async () => {
  const connected = await connection();
  const [rows] = await connected.execute('SELECT * FROM media');

  res.send(rows.length);
});
```

Comment: But still it my endpoint keep refresh. dont return the row. and give unhandled ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE